# Why is Windows folder so big in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

I recently installed Windows 8.1 on my laptop. I have the Windows folder on its own 64GB mSATA drive. For Windows 7 this was great because the Windows folder was small. With Windows 8.1 the drive is almost full, and the Windows folder takes up almost 20GB (the WinSXS folder takes up most of that space).

Is there a good reason that the Windows folder takes up so much space? Is there a way that I can cut down on some of the space that it takes up?

Comment: Windows gets incrementally larger with each update, service pack, major version upgrade. Nature of the beast.

Comment: Have a look at the Disk Cleanup tool in Windows.  It can get rid of temp files and the downloaded service packs that is already installed.  It won't save you much space, but you will be able to win a couple of MB's.

Comment: I realized that I forgot to disable hibernation (I have 32GB RAM).  For some reason it only cleared up about 6GB though... :/

Comment: @FiascoLabs Yeah, and that makes me mad.  Debian with Gnome only takes about 5GB and I have seriously been considering switching.

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the size of WinSXS most tools report the incorrect size of it anyways. If all you are doing is Properties on the Windows folder its not reporting the correct size of this folder anyways.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate.  The question mentions Win 7 as contrast, but the issue is with Win 8.1.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 8.1 gives allows you to forcibly remove all previous versions of uninstalled components, even ones that haven’t been around for more than 30 days. These commands must be run in an elevated Command Prompt — in other words, start the Command Prompt window as Administrator.
For example, the following command will uninstall all previous versions of components without the scheduled task’s 30-day grace period:

```
DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
```

The following command will remove files needed for uninstallation of service packs. You won’t be able to uninstall any currently installed service packs after running this command:

```
DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /SPSuperseded
```

The following command will remove all old versions of every component. You won’t be able to uninstall any currently installed service packs or updates after this completes:

```
DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup /ResetBase
```

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the search panel --> type in *Task Scheduler* -->  on the left go into *Microsoft* folder --> then *Windows* folder and search for --> *Servicing* folder , click on it --> now in the mid of the page a "start new component cleanup" will show up.  Right click it and select Run, then let the magic work.

It worked for me, 6-7 GB.

Comment: Also see the `/ResetBase` flag, but note that "Installed Windows updates can’t be uninstalled after running /StartComponentCleanup with the /ResetBase option.": http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825265.aspx