# Is windows 8.1 enterprise supposed to take up 27GB on a fresh install?

Tags: windows, windows-8, disk-space, visual-studio-2013

Windows 8.1 Enterprise + Visual Studio 2013 pro update 4 is taking 35.7 GB. (mind you I have not installed anything other than Google Chrome)

All I want this partition on my mac pros SSD is for Windows development. Do i really need 35.7 GB to do this? I.e. the lightest weight strategy for windows development.

I was clicking through folders looking for stuff to delete from windows. Any tips about what I can yank?

Also what if I took visual studio 2013 pro with no updates i save 3gbs. Is that a dumb idea?

Heres what I installed:

- Windows 8.1 Enterprise (not the N edition the space was only like 35 more mb)
- Visual Studio 2013 pro with update 4 the only option
  is the web dev tools (no sql server no silverlight etc)
- Google Chrome
- Thats it. No other ad ons from windows etc.

**Update Swing and miss v1**
[I tried the 3 steps listed in this question. That only freed up .2GB](https://superuser.com/questions/669193/why-is-windows-folder-so-big-in-windows-8-1).
Is Windows 8.1 enterprise and VS 2013 pro expected to take up 36 GB? My math says 9gb for Visual studio so windows 8.1 enterprise uses 27gb? something doesnt seem right here.

**Update Swing and miss v2**

- So the WinSxS folder can grow pretty large.
- However running the command below will tell you if you should even bother cleaning it up which in my case was a no.

> Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore

Comment: I deleted my old question because the assumption was I didnt try searching. I have actually done quite a bit searching to no positive conclusion to get the space windows takes up down.

Comment: There are various tools to remove features you are not going to use from the component store which will decrease the size of the Windows WinSxS directory.  As for VS that is the correct size.

Comment: run TreeSizeFree (as admin) and here you can see what uses most space: http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/ If you dualboot, you should disable hibernation to save space for the hiberfile.sys

Answer (score 1):

How much ram do you have, and by correlation, how big is you page/swap file?

I have 16GB of ram and Windows 8.1 tried to make a 16GB swap file. I turned it down to 1GB with a maximum 4GB. That saved a ton of space and it's unlikely that I'll run out of ram anyway.

Also, if you don't plan to use sleep, try the following in an elevated command prompt:

```
powercfg -H off
```

That will remove hiberfil.sys which is usally the same size as the amount of ram you have.

Note: The old, make your swap as big as your ram isn't used anymore. Now you set it for what you need. Unless you're doing a ton of graphic/video work, you can get by with far less.